# How can I get the event from cloudtrail for a codebuild project deployed?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cloudtrail

I have a codebuild project that was deployed in AWS and executed. In cloudtrail, how can I search the codebuild project arn to find out when/who deployed the job and executed it?

I have tried to search event name, source, type, but it gives me many events for different codebuild project, is there a way to search by the resource arn?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> is there a way to search by the resource arn?

Probably not with CT's search. But CT trials (assuming you have them enabled) stored in S3 can be search using Athena as explained in [Querying AWS CloudTrail Logs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/athena/latest/ug/cloudtrail-logs.html). This would allow you to run much more complicated queries against CT logs.